How can I stop port.postMessage() in a node.js worker from causing a memory leak?
I have this basic example of the problem:
//main.js
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');
const worker = new Worker('./worker.js');

worker.on('message', function (message) {

    //no-op

});

And:
//worker.js
const { parentPort } = require('worker_threads');

while (1) {

    const message = {foo: true};

    parentPort.postMessage(message);


}

This causes a rapid growth in memory usage.  Within seconds it's gigabytes.  Within a couple of minutes it's all the system memory, and the process is killed.  I've tried adding delete message; after the postMessage() call, and in the message handler of main.js.  Neither of these seem to have any effect.  I've tried running it natively, and in various node based docker containers; it's always the same.
My questions are:

Why does it work this way?  Why isn't the object being garbage collected when main.js's message handler is returning?  And if it's a case of postMessage() carelessly growing some message queue in the parent thread with freshly created objects, why does it do that, rather than waiting?

How do I get around this?


I imagine someone is thinking "Why would you send so many messages?".  The answer is to demonstrate the problem.  In the real scenario it was larger but much more infrequent message sends, and that caused a much slower but still completely unacceptable memory leak.
What's the deal here?

It looks like the worker thread is blocking the main thread. The worker writes and the main thread can't read.

How so?  The main thread reads the object fine.  I can log it out, etc.

This Stackblitz examples demonstrates the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jrpzbe?file=index.js The main thread starts reading after the worker loop finishes. I have the last worker write at 1730135284538 and the first main read at 1730135284539. Increasing the number of iterations doesn't change this behavior. The same observation with 1000 iterations mean, the worker writes 1000 messages before the main thread starts reading them.

A setTimeout seems to solve the problem. With this timeout, the worker doesn't block the main thread anymore.

Thanks.  It's taken me a while to mull this because in my original code, there is no infinite loop, and the thread is not blocking the main thread, yet the problem is the same.  I found that if I use setImmediate, your code causes the memory usage to explode also. The problem is the inclusion of a console.log() statement, for some crazy reason.  Anyway, I've simply taken that out, and it works, and I don't know why.  Oh well.

If I correctly understand, the code in the question doesn't reproduce the actual problem. It shows a different problem. Since the question is already correctly answered for the code in the question, you shouldn't edit it. If you still have a question, you could ask a new question.

Honestly it's hard to tell because I still don't know what's actually happening to cause the memory explosion.  setImmediate with console logs in the message handler reproduces at least that.  a while(true) loop does too.  a setTimeout with console.logs does not.  a setImmediate without console.logs does not.  It's weird, and I've given up.  Sorry to future searchers.

The problem seems to be from here
//worker.js
const { parentPort } = require('worker_threads');

while (1) {
    const message = {foo: true};

    parentPort.postMessage(message);

}

Your code is using an infinite loop to repeatedly send messages back to your main thread which will cause the GC to be overwhelmed and eventually kill the process.
So your garbage collector is actually collecting the object but it is just overwhelmed by having too many objects being sent to it.
A potential work around is to put some sort of break in your loop that will give your GC sufficient time to clear up all the objects in the heap.
I think you can use setTimeout to add this delay.
Hope this helps
